# Connecting to SQL Server from Nodejs

Tags: node.js, sql-server-2008, node-seriate

I am working on a sample application using Node js
and SQL server 2008.

To access SQL server from node js am using seriate [http://developer.leankit.com/painless-sql-server-with-nodejs-and-seriate/].

Below is my sample code

File ./DBLayer/db.js code

```
var sql = require("seriate");

var config = {
"server": "127.0.0.1",
"user": "sa",
"password": "12kafour~9999",
"database": "Tickets"
};

sql.setDefaultConfig( config );

exports.sqlDb = sql;
```

And file app.js code

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var sqlDb = require('./DBLayer/db.js');

//-- set the view engine
app.set('view engine' , 'ejs');

app.use( bodyParser.json() );       // to support JSON-encoded bodies

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({     // to support URL-encoded bodies ??
  extended: true
}));

//-- set the routes
app.get('/login' , function(req , res){
//-- set the view to render
res.render('login' , {title:'Login Screen' , error : ''});
});

app.post('/login' , function(req , res) {

 sqlDb.execute( {
      query: "SELECT count(*) FROM USERS WHERE LOGIN ='" + req.body.username   + "'" + "AND PASSWORD = '" + req.body.pwd + "'"
  } ).then( function( results ) {
      res.render('login' , {title:'Login Screen' , error : 'u r the one...'});
  }, function( err ) {
      res.render('login' , {title:'Login Screen' , error : 'Invalid Login/Password.'});
  });
});

 //-- set the port
 var server = app.listen(3000 , function() {
 console.log('Server Ready..')
 });
```

When user enters username and password and submits am getting
"TypeError: sqlDb.execute is not a function" error.

I am not sure why I am getting this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change this line:

```
var sqlDb = require('./DBLayer/db.js');
```

to

```
var sqlDb = require('./DBLayer/db.js').sqlDb;
```

or to change this line:

```
exports.sqlDb = sql;
```

to

```
exports = sql;
```

**Explanation:** In Node when you do:`var sqlDb = require('./DBLayer/db.js');`
 it make sqlDb to be the `exports` object.

So in your code you have `exports.sqlDb = sql`. The compiler is right exports don't have execute function. exports only have 1 var, `exports.sqlDb`.

---

**Bonus Tip:** If you really want you code to work, without change `app.js` you can add this to the end of your module:

```
exports.execute=function(){
    return sql.execute.call(sql,arguments)
}
```